# How can I use the value of a jQuery variable in c# (cshtml)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core, razor

I have a jQuery function and I need the value of this variable in my c# code. The function looks like this:

```
let dropdownList = document.getElementById('betreffDropdown');
dropdownList.onchange = (ev) => {    
  let selectedIndex = dropdownList.value;
}
```

I want to search in my database with this code snippet:

```
var templatee = Model.Templates.Distinct().ToList();    
var currentTemplate = templatee.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Item2 == selectedIndex).Item1;
```

My Dropdown looks like this:

```
@if (Model.Templates != null)
{

    foreach (var template in Model.Templates.Distinct())
    {
        <option>@template.Item2</option>
    }
}
```

My Controller Method looks like this now:

```
private readonly TemplatesVM templatesVM;
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetValueOfDropdown(string selectedIndex)
        {

            var templatee = templatesVM.Templates.Distinct().ToList();
            var currentTemplate = templatee.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Item2 == selectedIndex).Item1;

            return Json(currentTemplate);
        }
```

How can I use the value of "selectedIndex" in my code? or is there a way to get the selected value of a dropdown directly in the c# code?

I researched and tried some solutions from problems which looks similar to my problem but nothing worked

Comment: what do you mean about `use the value of "selectedIndex" in my code?`, How do you want to use this value?

Comment: to search in a list:     
var currentTemplate = templatee.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Item2 == selectedIndex).Item1;

Comment: So you wanna use this value in backend to search in db by linq? In my opinion, in your onchange method, you can send an ajax to backend with this value.

Comment: yes exactly! Do you have an example for an ajax request? Or a link or smth? But my jQuery and c# code works when i enter a string as the search value. You know what I mean?

Comment: Maybe you can provide your related code and i can change it to a work demo.

Comment: where can I provide my code?

Comment: Just update your question and provide code.

Comment: Is this all you need?

Comment: After you get the value in backend, Do you want to return the result to frontend then show it in the page?

Comment: Yes then i would like to show the message related to the subject in the frontend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple demo about how to achieve your goal, Hope it can help you solve this issue.

Because you don't provide your model design, So here is my model in demo:

```
public class Templates
    {
        public string Item1 { get; set; }
        public string Item2 { get; set; }
    }
```

For test convenience, I just hard code here, in your demo, you save the data into db.

```
List<Templates> templates = new List<Templates> {
            new Templates
            {
                Item1 = "Test1",
                Item2 = "AAA"
            },
            new Templates
            {
                Item1 = "Test2",
                Item2 = "BBB"
            },
            new Templates
            {
                Item1 = "Test3",
                Item2 = "CCC"
            },
            new Templates
            {
                Item1 = "Test4",
                Item2 = "DDD"
            },
            new Templates
            {
                Item1 = "Test5",
                Item2 = "EEE"
            },
            new Templates
            {
                Item1 = "Test6",
                Item2 = "FFF"
            }

        };
```

FrontEnd

```
@model IEnumerable<Templates>

<form>
    <select id="select">
        @if (Model != null)
        {

            foreach (var template in Model.Distinct())
            {
                <option value="@template.Item2">@template.Item2</option>
            }
        }
    </select>

    <h1 id="result">

    </h1>
</form>

@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $("#select").change(function (){
            var value = $("#select option:selected").val();
            var data = {
                "selectedIndex" : value
            };

            $.ajax({
                type: 'Get',
                url: '/Demo/GetItem1/',
                data: data,
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#result").html(data)
                },

            })
        });
    </script>
}
```

BackEnd

```
public IActionResult GetItem1(string selectedIndex)
        {
            var currentTemplate = templates.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Item2 == selectedIndex).Item1;
            return Json(currentTemplate);
        }
```

Demo

[image]

Comment: Hi @citr0q, Have this answer solved your issue?

Comment: It looks very good! THANK YOU VERY MUCH! But what is "templates" in the backend snipped? When I copy and paste it, an error occurs....

Comment: Because I hard code in my demo like `List<Templates> templates = new List<Templates>{.......}`, It is just the name of List<Templates>. You can just replace it in your demo.

Comment: @citr0q, Have you solved this issue now?

Comment: nope i dont know what I should use there

Comment: You just need to use your original code `var templatee = Model.Templates.Distinct().ToList();    
var currentTemplate = templatee.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Item2 == selectedIndex).Item1;` in backend, The backend i posted just use the value(selectedIndex) passed from frontend to select data in database, So you just need to replace it to your original query code.

Comment: Whe I do this i get a System.NullReferenceException: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252649/discussion-between-xinran-shen-and-citr0q).